# How do I get the formula separator in a script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, locale, google-sheets-formula

I have a basic Google Sheets script and as part of the HTML sidebar I show the user the formula to type in; e.g. `=myformula("bob", "ross")`. This works for people in the U.S. and a lot of other countries but there are quite a few countries that use `;` instead, so the formula looks like `=myformula("bob"; "ross")`. I know I can probably get the locale of the spreadsheet via a script but is there a way to get whether I should put a `,` or a `;`? Thanks!

Comment: Let watch this https://youtu.be/ljvB2arCsNQ someone's already make the video for it, I hope it will be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`;` is universally accepted(except in case of array literals). It'll automatically be parsed to `,` in the US and other locales.

Comment: Oh, I wish it was the other way around, sadly. Most of my users are in the U.S. and I don't want to confuse them by showing a `;` in the formula....thanks though

Comment: @user It won't show as `;` in sheet. When you set as `;`, it'll automatically be converted to `,` in sheet.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking about what I show them to enter as I don't actually enter the formula for them