# Sharing a sheet with formulas separated by commas to someone in a region that uses semi-colons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that I want to share with various people. The formulas I use are input through Apps Script as they need to be changed.  I separate the various parts by commas. For example,

```js
function example(){sheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula("=SUM(10, 20)")}
```

Some of the people I share with have settings to use semi-colons. For example,

```js
function example2(){sheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula("=SUM(10; 20)")}
```

They get an #ERROR for all my formulas. I did some research but don't see a general solution for when they are input by apps script. I would have thought Google would translate the formulas but it doesn't seem so when they are input with range.setformula.

I found [this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-change-a-non-regional-google-sheets-formula/), but it just seems to help figure out how to change it. I want it to change automatically or somehow function for anyone who opens it.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using United States as Locale, Google Sheets supports `SUM(10, 20)` and `SUM(10; 20)` but using a Locale that uses comma as decimal separator, i.e. Argentina, doesn't, so what about this "fix"

instead of using `SUM(10, 20)` use `SUM(10; 20)`

in other words, use semicolon always as the formula parameter separator.

Related

- [How do I get the formula separator in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61283095/1595451)

Comment: With a UK Locale, the ; is converted to a , after pressing Enter.....

Comment: my point is that even by typing in the formula with semi-colons, google sheets then converts them to commas.

Comment: @MetricRat This question is about using Apps Script, so when I said use semicolon always as the formula parameter separator it's implicit that this refers to scripts, not to writing formulas on the Google Sheets UI.